# How to override subscr_success.html email template in custom theme Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, email-templates, newsletter

I need to change the content of newsletter success email. I tried to override the subscr_success.html file in \Magento_Newsletter\templates\email\ folder in my custom theme. But it cannot be overridden. Can anyone suggest how can I do this? Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 3):

**You need to add your email tempaltes file directly to email folder  without create templates folder,**

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/Magento_Newsletter/email/subscr_success.html
```

run command from system root folder,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have issue yet.

Comment: No issues.. Actually I had given wrong path.. Now its fixed after giving the right path..

Comment: You can close this issue after accept as solutions so other users have useful in future.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to confirm Rakesh answer is working on Magento 2.4.2

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/Magento_Newsletter/email/subscr_success.html
```